# Why is my Iterator empty?

Tags: java

I have an Iterator that should be being populated by the FileUtils.iterateFiles() function using an instance of IOFileFilter to sort through and return an iterator of files matching the title "sound".

The problem is, even though i can see the accept(File file) override in the IOFileFilter returning true (via breakpoint), when i query iterator.hasNext(), I get false, and debug shows that the iterator is empty. Can anybody spot any possible causes? Or do Iterators and IOFileFiltters not behave in the way in which i think they do?

Code below.

```
private IOFileFilter findSoundsDir = new IOFileFilter()
{
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.getName().equals("sounds"); //Breakpoint here gets hit
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file, String s) {
        return s.equals("sounds");
    }
};

public void generateSoundEmbeds(String baseDir)
{
    File searchingDir = new File(baseDir).getParentFile().getParentFile();
    System.out.println("searchingDir: " + searchingDir.getAbsolutePath());
    Iterator<File> soundsIterator = (Iterator<File>)FileUtils.iterateFiles(searchingDir, findSoundsDir ,TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);

    if(soundsIterator.hasNext()) //however this check returns false, despite IOFileFilter returning true at least once previously
    {
        //we never get here
    }else{
        System.out.println("found no file");
    }
}
```

Comment: off the record, could you just avoid `if(true) return true else return false`

Comment: The entire body of IOFileFilter.accept(File) boils down to this: `return file.getName().equals("sounds");`

Comment: Yes, of course. I only added it here so that i didn't have to evaluate 
"file.getAbsolutePath().substring(file.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(File.separator)+1).equals("sounds")" every time i ran.

Comment: @rob thanks for the tip. I'm not familiar with java at all.